Как всегда отображать спрайт поверх окна диалога в RenPy?
Пытался сделать так, чтобы спрайт персонажа был поверх экрана диалога. И у меня получилось при помощи side в названии спрайта персонажа. Но мне нужно, чтобы спрайт этого персонажа не пропадал во время реплик других, а всегда оставался на месте
define l = Character('Лиза', color="#7c104fe5", image='lisa')

image side lisa = "side lisa.png"


label start:

scene bg class

show lisa:

    yalign 1.0


Возможно, свой ответ вы найдете здесь: https://otvet.mail.ru/question/236465830?ysclid=m0i8pscwso630850165
Здесь задаётся такой же вопрос,что и у вас. На него имеется ответ и даже приведён пример кода.

Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.
